# How to instantiate and initialize variable at single line

Tags: powershell

How to do below on single line?
After line is executed value of **$b is null**

```
 $b = ([System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,object]]::new()).Add("dd",$null)
```

or

```
[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,object]]::new()).Add("dd",$null) -eq $null
True
```

Comment: `($b = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,object]]::new()).Add("dd",$null)`

Comment: Code does not work, $b is null

Comment: PestSerAI code works fine if you remove unprintable characters in new() above if pasted into powershell

Comment: 3rd Google result for "Powershell Initialise Variable". Any reason not to do it on two lines? If the objective is simply to do the same on one line as you can on two, no two line example provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
($b = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,object]]::new()).Add("dd",$null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [hash tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) instead of .NET dictionaries. These are `System.Collections.Hashtable` objects that store key-value pairs. In PowerShell, you can use the operator `@{}` to create a hash table, and can quickly initialize one with several values on a single line.

You'll effectively get the same behavior with a hash table as you would a dictionary, except perhaps some performance differences and more noticably -- the lack of strong typing of your values.

**Simple demo:**

```
PS C:> @{ "dd" = $null }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
dd
```

**To convert from a hash table to a dictionary in PowerShell in a single line:**

```
$dictionary = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,object]'; (@{ "dd" = $null }).Keys | % { $dictionary.Add($_, $hashtable.Item($_)) }
```